# Make a textbox click a button if you hit enter

Tags: javascript, html, web

So I have looked at some previous example online and it seems prettys strait forward

```
    <form:input path="searchParameter.instanceName" id="searchBox" onkeydown="if (event.keyCode == 13){ document.getElementById('btnSearch').click() return false }"/>
```

And it works fine with firefox but it does not work at all with I.E. 7 it just submits the form. Any idea wh

Comment: I don't remember HTML being namespaced, nor `input` elements having a `path` attribute

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be missing a semicolon.

```
document.getElementById('btnSearch').click(); return false ;
```